# Use SNMP to transfer file from agent to manager?

Tags: .net, snmp

I want invoke my .NET assembly from snmp agent and return an XML document to the agent in order to transmit that XML file to the server (manager).

Can I use SNMP to transmit big files to the manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The max size of an SNMP PDU is 64k (i.e. the max size of a UDP datagram). Some implementations may have smaller limits. Some networks will not pass large datagrams cleanly (they may get fragmented and not reliably reassembled).

You don't want to transfer a file through SNMP. Use a more suitable protocol: TFTP, FTP, HTTP, SCP all come to mind, depending on the needs of your application.